# Portable Windows IMAP client

Tags: windows, email, portable, imap

What portable IMAP client for Windows?

I tried Sylpheed, which works well enough, although it leaves lots of remnants on close. While you can ask it to delete temporary files, it doesn't delete **all** of them. Moreover, it leaves an account details file with user and password, in *plain text*.